# docker Buildx "ERROR: BuildKit is enabled but the buildx component is missing or broken" error

Tags: docker, wsl-2, buildx

When I try to do a Docker Build using Docker as usual, I get the error message in the image and cannot Build.
What should I do in this case?
By the way, Docker's version is 23.0.1.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzgNi.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIryk.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMF5Y.png)

When I uninstall docker buildx and then Build, I get other warning errors and the Build itself works, but parallel processing cannot be performed.
My ideal would be to use Buildx to do a parallel Build.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also had a similar issue with version `23.0.2`. For me it was missing buildx package. Following command solved the issue.

`apt-get install docker-buildx-plugin`

Message and docs of docker on linux are a bit vague unfortunately. I found out the missing package while I was planning to install docker from scratch.

Answer (score 14):

Did you maybe use Docker Desktop on Windows, uninstall it, and then tried to install Docker directly on WSL?

In that case you may have an issue that in /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/ you don't have actual files, but broken links to WSL installation. This happened to me.

To verify check output from: `ls -la /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/`

In my case, I `rm` these broken links, then rerun Docker installation on WSL and it solved the problem.

Comment: In my case it was sufficient to just remove these old/broken symlinks. I did not have to reinstall docker. I did run the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin docker-scan-plugin` though, but this command did not restore any symlinks/files in that directory.

Comment: Ironically, the `--reinstall` flag was what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete solution:

1. Find the name of the missing system package using substring search with `apt cache`:

```bash
$ apt cache buildx
docker-buildx-plugin - Docker Buildx cli plugin.
```

2. Update packages lists and install the required package (using `apt` - newer version of `apt-get` - and standard user with `sudo`, rather than `root`):

```bash
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y docker-buildx-plugin
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had docker desktop for windows installed and wsl2 and ubuntu on windows. When i uninstalled docker desktop this error started appearing. **Reinstalling docker desktop** made things work again.

Uninstalling docker desktop removes or changes some files it seems that breaks docker in wsl.