# Docker BuildKit is broken

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just installed Linux Mint on my laptop and updated it and after these steps I started installing docker, after installation I just ran the command `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose up --build` and gave me an error :

```
Error: BuildKit is enabled but the buildx component is missing broken.
       Install the buidlx component to buidl images with BuildKit ....
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739545/docker-buildx-error-buildkit-is-enabled-but-the-buildx-component-is-missing-or

Did you try simply doing `sudo apt-get install docker-buildx-plugin`

Comment: @LNiederha, it's rigth, but befor executing this command, need execute next command: curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh. Thanks!